# SparkContext textFile with localfile system throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In my spark application I need to lookup a small input file from local filesystem.

So, I tried to load the file as sc.textFile("file:///AbsolutePathToFile");

When I run this program with spark-submit (in local mode)it throws the following exception:

```
14/11/25 17:27:30 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: For input string: "0"
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.parseBoolean(StringLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toBoolean(StringLike.scala:226)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toBoolean(StringOps.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$$anonfun$getBoolean$2.apply(SparkConf.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$$anonfun$getBoolean$2.apply(SparkConf.scala:184)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.getBoolean(SparkConf.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$6.apply(Executor.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$6.apply(Executor.scala:323)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:158)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
14/11/25 17:27:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: For input string: "0"
        scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.parseBoolean(StringLike.scala:238)
        scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toBoolean(StringLike.scala:226)
        scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toBoolean(StringOps.scala:31)
        org.apache.spark.SparkConf$$anonfun$getBoolean$2.apply(SparkConf.scala:184)
        org.apache.spark.SparkConf$$anonfun$getBoolean$2.apply(SparkConf.scala:184)
        scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        org.apache.spark.SparkConf.getBoolean(SparkConf.scala:184)
        org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:356)
        org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$6.apply(Executor.scala:325)
        org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$6.apply(Executor.scala:323)
        scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
        scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
        scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
        scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
        scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
        scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
        scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
        org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:323)
        org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:158)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

But the same code works fine in eclipse configure with spark-scala.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Also, let me know is there any difference between executing the program from eclipse IDE and spark submit.

Comment: Can you run any Spark job locally? Because thebacktrace doesn't immediately seem related to textFile. Can you run a do-nothing job (that initalises a Spark context etc, but does no real processing) without errors?

Comment: I just ran sparkpi example program and its working fine.